# State into index of array gives error REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm having issue where when i put my state into index of an array, it gives error.

Here is there line of bug :           {WorkData[state].title}

What i need to do is to display the elements of WorkData which is a array with objects  : title, content, img math etc...

```
    const WorkData = [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: 'title',
        subtext: 'React/Express',
        content: 'content',
        imgPath: 'imgPath',
      },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Little Hero Academy',
    subtext: 'React/API REST',
    content:
      'content,
    imgPath: 'imgPath',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title',
    subtext: 'subtext',
    content: 'content',
    imgPath: 'imgPath',
  },
```

First, i have a list of cards with a button that contains data:

```
<div className="work-container flex">
  <div className="work-bloc zoom">
    <div className="work-hover" />
    <div className="work-text">
      <div className="text-title">{WorkData[0].title}</div>
      <span className="subtext">{WorkData[0].subtext}</span>
    </div>
    <div
      onClick={togglePopup}
      data-id={WorkData[0].id}
      className="work-showmore button2"
    >
      Show More
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I store the data in state with this function :

```
 const [id, setId] = useState();

  const togglePopup = (e) => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    setId(e.target.dataset.id);
  };
```

I need that data to get to the popup,

```
        <Popup
          togglePopup={togglePopup}
          closePopup={closePopup}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          id={id}
        />
```

I pass the state to my popup component and try to display the value of id which is displayed
Also,i need to make the popup display of the content of the array that belong to the id (index) i passed in state :  workData 1 2 3 etc...

```
const Popup = ({ closePopup, isOpen, id }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`popup-container ${isOpen ? 'opened' : 'closed'}`}>
      <div className={`popup ${isOpen ? 'opened2' : 'closed2'}`}>
        <span className='popup-title'>
          {WorkData[id].title}
          {id}
        </span>
        <div className='image-container'>
          <img
            src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/1060/536/354.jpg?blur=2&hmac=0zJLs1ar00sBbW5Ahd_4zA6pgZqCVavwuHToO6VtcYY'
            alt=''
          />
        </div>
        <p>
          Team projet with React and API REST. Our goal was to make an app with
          a choosen API and make something out of it. We did a superhero-themed
          website with games for children.
          <br />
          Check on <AiFillGithub className='menuicon' />
        </p>
        <div onClick={closePopup} className='close-icon button2'>
          Show less{' '}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

but i get this error :

```
**TypeError: _WorkData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default[id] is undefined**
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: It might be worth also including a more complete example, these snippets individually are useful, but they don't let us see the entire flow of the data, which you generally need when debugging an undefined variable.

Comment: share the state initialization.

Comment: @JuniusL.  i updated my post with more code, with states and the full pop up components, tell me if it helps. I can also post full code on Gist if you want to

Comment: try ```const [id, setId] = useState(0);```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed, it i changed the way of doing it, i mapped my workcard components so i can easily retrieve the id, title, etc, and i didnt change the event onclick to catch the card.id in state, i passed the state to parent, then to the popup, and then into the popup component i just imported the WorkData.js  and simply did : WorkData[state-with-id].title etc

See sample of code below

```
   works.js

  const togglePopup = (e) => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    setPopupId(e.target.dataset.id);
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(workData);
  }, []);
```

workcards.js

```
 <div
    onClick={togglePopup}
    className='work-showmore button2'
    data-id={workcard.id}
  >
```

popup.js

```
import workData from './workData';
<span className='popup-title'>{workData[popupId].title}</span>
```